# What type of script it is which is begin with a hash sign # among html

Tags: html

I saw html lines in a java-based web project like this below:

```
#if($!url) 
    <script>    
      var count=3;
      window.setInterval(go,1000);

    </script> 
#end
```

I'd like to know what's the if block with a # sign is. Which script? Since it seems not PHP or ruby. What's that?

Thanks for the quick answer. Cool!

Comment: Some template engine. Where did you see it?

Comment: In a java based project source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is Velocity. Take a look at this section: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#if-elseif-else

Comment: Such a quick help. Thank you and Ry!